# NoClassFoundError in an Android App

Tags: android

HI guys,
I have a problem that I am getting an error as NoClassFound Error in an Activity which is already added in a Manifest File. Thing is that I am using FBRocket jar for Facebook implementation. For this we have to implements LoginListner interface to your Activity. And when we implement this interface this error occurred. How this problem be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the FBRocket jar to your apk ?

Comment: yes sir I already added. If this was the question then I had asked this question man.

Answer (score 0):

Places the jar on buildpath (right click on jar to do this), so that it can be used to compilation as well as while preparing apk.