# Service.autodiscoverUrl() ews-android-api doesn´t work

Tags: java, android, http, exchangewebservices

I´m using ews-android-api for connect with Exchange servers. The problem appears when I try to use the Service.autodiscoverUrl() tool for get the server URL using the user´s email.

This is my piece of code where I implement the autodiscover:

```
ExchangeService service;
service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(this.email, this.mPassword, this.domain);
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.autodiscoverUrl(this.email);
```

And this is the error:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.javax.naming.ldap.LdapName**

Could anyone tell me what´s wrong or show me how to do properly the autodiscoverURL?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassFoundError in an Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960057/noclassfounderror-in-an-android-app)

Comment: Please try to build the https://github.com/alipov/ews-android-api/tree/dns-query-fix branch and let me know if it solves your issue.